# Си ошибка error: expected expression before '>' token

Tags: c++, c

C код:

```
if (ball.x <= HEIGHT && ball.y <= WIDHT){
            printf("1 Start\n");
            while(ball.x <= HEIGHT && ball.y <= WIDHT){
                Sleep(1000);
                printf("X:\t%d\nY:\t%d\n\n", ball.x,ball.y);
                ball.x++;
                ball.y++;
            }
            printf("1 close");
        
        };
        // 2 
        if (ball.x => HEIGHT && ball.y => WIDHT){
            printf("2 Start\n");
            while(ball.x => HEIGHT && ball.y => WIDHT){
                Sleep(1000);
                printf("X:\t%d\nY:\t%d\n\n", ball.x,ball.y);
                ball.x--;
                ball.y--;
            }
            printf("2 close");
        
        };
        // 3
        if (ball.x => HEIGHT && ball.y <= WIDHT){
            printf("3 Start\n");
            while(ball.x => HEIGHT && ball.y <= WIDHT){
                Sleep(1000);
                printf("X:\t%d\nY:\t%d\n\n", ball.x,ball.y);
                ball.x--;
                ball.y++;
            }
            printf("3 close");
        
        }
        // 4
        if (ball.x <= HEIGHT && ball.y => WIDHT){
            printf("4 Start\n");
            while(ball.x <= HEIGHT && ball.y => WIDHT){
                Sleep(1000);
                printf("X:\t%d\nY:\t%d\n\n", ball.x,ball.y);
                ball.x++;
                ball.y--;
            }
            printf("1 close");
        
        }
```

Ошибка при компиляции:

```
main.c: In function 'main':
main.c:30:15: error: expected expression before '>' token
   30 |   if (ball.x => HEIGHT && ball.y => WIDHT){
      |               ^
main.c:32:18: error: expected expression before '>' token
   32 |    while(ball.x => HEIGHT && ball.y => WIDHT){
      |                  ^
main.c:42:15: error: expected expression before '>' token
   42 |   if (ball.x => HEIGHT && ball.y <= WIDHT){
      |               ^
main.c:44:18: error: expected expression before '>' token
   44 |    while(ball.x => HEIGHT && ball.y <= WIDHT){
      |                  ^
main.c:54:35: error: expected expression before '>' token
   54 |   if (ball.x <= HEIGHT && ball.y => WIDHT){
      |                                   ^
main.c:56:38: error: expected expression before '>' token
   56 |    while(ball.x <= HEIGHT && ball.y => WIDHT){
      |
```

Comment: `>=` вместо `=>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Неправильно записали оператор сравнения. Надо `>=` вместо `=>`.